Why I need an RPC URL to call a view function in Solidity
hello so my question is why I should need a RPC Url while calling a view function
Here is my simple code that is deployed in the localhost anvil testnet and that run successfully and there I did not use the --rpc-url to call the view function.
I just used
cast call <ContractAddress> "retrieve()"

and it successfully go off
This is the command list
➜  foundry-simple-storage-f24 git:(master) ✗ forge script script/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol --rpc
-url $RPC_URL --private-key 0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80 -
-broadcast -vvvv
[⠰] Compiling...
No files changed, compilation skipped
Traces:
  [317505] DeploySimpleStorage::run()
    ├─ [0] VM::startBroadcast()
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ [281718] → new SimpleStorage@0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0
    │   └─ ← [Return] 1407 bytes of code
    ├─ [0] VM::stopBroadcast()
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    └─ ← [Return] SimpleStorage: [0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0]


Script ran successfully.

== Return ==
0: contract SimpleStorage 0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0

## Setting up 1 EVM.
==========================
Simulated On-chain Traces:

  [281718] → new SimpleStorage@0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0
    └─ ← [Return] 1407 bytes of code


==========================

Chain 31337

Estimated gas price: 2.755951468 gwei

Estimated total gas used for script: 464097

Estimated amount required: 0.001279028808444396 ETH

==========================

##### anvil-hardhat
✅  [Success]Hash: 0x2105048c17119f6b4f8e1f0829a0fed8543e6ac6446b54de0d59cc433a28393d
Contract Address: 0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0
Block: 3
Paid: 0.000632346209915232 ETH (357088 gas * 1.770841389 gwei)

✅ Sequence #1 on anvil-hardhat | Total Paid: 0.000632346209915232 ETH (357088 gas * avg 1.770841389 gwei)
                                                                                                

==========================

ONCHAIN EXECUTION COMPLETE & SUCCESSFUL.

Transactions saved to: /home/debayan/Desktop/web3.0/foundry-f24/foundry-simple-storage-f24/broadcast/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol/31337/run-latest.json

Sensitive values saved to: /home/debayan/Desktop/web3.0/foundry-f24/foundry-simple-storage-f24/cache/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol/31337/run-latest.json

➜  foundry-simple-storage-f24 git:(master) ✗ cast send 0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0 "store(uint256)" 345 --rpc-url $RPC_URL --interactive
Enter private key:

blockHash               0x6c44bae2adc696eab42154c75dc762189ddd4c0343c30f00d0689fd228cd96bb
blockNumber             4
contractAddress         
cumulativeGasUsed       43550
effectiveGasPrice       1676780034
from                    0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
gasUsed                 43550
logs                    []
logsBloom               0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
root                    
status                  1 (success)
transactionHash         0xec18e1bca172e4bcca15e971f844eb63d250f3383bcd45e42aaee39b616b92b9
transactionIndex        0
type                    2
blobGasPrice            1
blobGasUsed             
authorizationList       
to                      0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0
➜  foundry-simple-storage-f24 git:(master) ✗ cast call 0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0 "retrieve()"
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000159
➜  foundry-simple-storage-f24 git:(master) ✗

But when I tried to deploy it using the Alchemy provided Sepolia testnet it gave me a bug.
Actually the contract deployed successfully and also the non-view (store) function goes off successfully and the balance is deducted from my sepolia metamask but after calling the
cast call <ContractAddress> "retrieve()" 

It gave me a
0x

This is the sample command lines

foundry-simple-storage-f24 git:(master) ✗ forge script script/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL --account sepoliaWallet --sender 0x13bbf2898f904e9d206ab5363e25fe29be83103d --broadcast -vvvv
[⠢] Compiling...
No files changed, compilation skipped
Traces:
  [317505] DeploySimpleStorage::run()
    ├─ [0] VM::startBroadcast()
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ [281718] → new SimpleStorage@0x2d818BB5F262564d835cbdd641dc0E5dA9e3CDb6
    │   └─ ← [Return] 1407 bytes of code
    ├─ [0] VM::stopBroadcast()
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    └─ ← [Return] SimpleStorage: [0x2d818BB5F262564d835cbdd641dc0E5dA9e3CDb6]


Script ran successfully.

== Return ==
0: contract SimpleStorage 0x2d818BB5F262564d835cbdd641dc0E5dA9e3CDb6

## Setting up 1 EVM.
==========================
Simulated On-chain Traces:

  [281718] → new SimpleStorage@0x2d818BB5F262564d835cbdd641dc0E5dA9e3CDb6
    └─ ← [Return] 1407 bytes of code


==========================

Chain 11155111

Estimated gas price: 0.726680521 gwei

Estimated total gas used for script: 464097

Estimated amount required: 0.000337250249754537 ETH

==========================
Enter keystore password:

##### sepolia
✅  [Success]Hash: 0x44d425d91eb543cf15cf44e4300a67b809801362cbd926b52413ae562807a2be
Contract Address: 0x2d818BB5F262564d835cbdd641dc0E5dA9e3CDb6
Block: 6957412
Paid: 0.00015515424143312 ETH (357088 gas * 0.434498615 gwei)

✅ Sequence #1 on sepolia | Total Paid: 0.00015515424143312 ETH (357088 gas * avg 0.434498615 gwei)
                                                                                                

==========================

ONCHAIN EXECUTION COMPLETE & SUCCESSFUL.

Transactions saved to: /home/debayan/Desktop/web3.0/foundry-f24/foundry-simple-storage-f24/broadcast/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol/11155111/run-latest.json

Sensitive values saved to: /home/debayan/Desktop/web3.0/foundry-f24/foundry-simple-storage-f24/cache/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol/11155111/run-latest.json

➜  foundry-simple-storage-f24 git:(master) ✗ cast send 0x2d818BB5F262564d835cbdd641dc0E5dA9e3CDb6 --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL --interactive
^C
➜  foundry-simple-storage-f24 git:(master) ✗ cast send 0x2d818BB5F262564d835cbdd641dc0E5dA9e3CDb6 "store(uint256)" 2333 --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL --interactive
Enter private key:

blockHash               0x0b6053d3dcd91e280a6dea689776b9410011e6ff41a175f27e0af9880d30828f
blockNumber             6957423
contractAddress         
cumulativeGasUsed       7258859
effectiveGasPrice       489573580
from                    0x13bBf2898F904e9D206ab5363E25Fe29be83103d
gasUsed                 43550
logs                    []
logsBloom               0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
root                    
status                  1 (success)
transactionHash         0x29b29a69ba3b9af2b83c2d525532fd2f3e258bed570b2361ead4b52cdec029c2
transactionIndex        48
type                    2
blobGasPrice            
blobGasUsed             
authorizationList       
to                      0x2d818BB5F262564d835cbdd641dc0E5dA9e3CDb6
➜  foundry-simple-storage-f24 git:(master) ✗ cast call 0x2d818BB5F262564d835cbdd641dc0E5dA9e3CDb6 "retrieve()"
0x
➜  foundry-simple-storage-f24 git:(master) ✗

but after using the --rpc-url It goes off
  foundry-simple-storage-f24 git:(master) ✗ forge script script/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL --account sepoliaWallet --sender 0x13bbf2898f904e9d206ab5363e25fe29be83103d --broadcast -vvvv
[⠢] Compiling...
No files changed, compilation skipped
Traces:
  [317505] DeploySimpleStorage::run()
    ├─ [0] VM::startBroadcast()
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ [281718] → new SimpleStorage@0x94d9ba56C4F7D1c7890d59ce71ac77c098448907
    │   └─ ← [Return] 1407 bytes of code
    ├─ [0] VM::stopBroadcast()
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    └─ ← [Return] SimpleStorage: [0x94d9ba56C4F7D1c7890d59ce71ac77c098448907]


Script ran successfully.

== Return ==
0: contract SimpleStorage 0x94d9ba56C4F7D1c7890d59ce71ac77c098448907

## Setting up 1 EVM.
==========================
Simulated On-chain Traces:

  [281718] → new SimpleStorage@0x94d9ba56C4F7D1c7890d59ce71ac77c098448907
    └─ ← [Return] 1407 bytes of code


==========================

Chain 11155111

Estimated gas price: 2.649761818 gwei

Estimated total gas used for script: 464097

Estimated amount required: 0.001229746510448346 ETH

==========================
Enter keystore password:

##### sepolia
✅  [Success]Hash: 0x342fb364836a3946784172f7d7a99ae0208040e957155bc226bc13d432f462d1
Contract Address: 0x94d9ba56C4F7D1c7890d59ce71ac77c098448907
Block: 6957523
Paid: 0.000418398098465024 ETH (357088 gas * 1.171694648 gwei)

✅ Sequence #1 on sepolia | Total Paid: 0.000418398098465024 ETH (357088 gas * avg 1.171694648 gwei)
                                                                                                                                                                              

==========================

ONCHAIN EXECUTION COMPLETE & SUCCESSFUL.

Transactions saved to: /home/debayan/Desktop/web3.0/foundry-f24/foundry-simple-storage-f24/broadcast/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol/11155111/run-latest.json

Sensitive values saved to: /home/debayan/Desktop/web3.0/foundry-f24/foundry-simple-storage-f24/cache/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol/11155111/run-latest.json

➜  foundry-simple-storage-f24 git:(master) ✗ cast send 0x94d9ba56C4F7D1c7890d59ce71ac77c098448907 "store(uint256)" 345 --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL --interactive
Enter private key:
^C
➜  foundry-simple-storage-f24 git:(master) ✗ cast send 0x94d9ba56C4F7D1c7890d59ce71ac77c098448907 "store(uint256)" 345 --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL --interactive
Enter private key:

blockHash               0x48a254346b7066322d5d01ae7b479fc126baecb7e02c7b44b6c87dfba55e894e
blockNumber             6957533
contractAddress         
cumulativeGasUsed       16810616
effectiveGasPrice       1347962882
from                    0x13bBf2898F904e9D206ab5363E25Fe29be83103d
gasUsed                 23650
logs                    []
logsBloom               0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
root                    
status                  1 (success)
transactionHash         0xb0f1101c43460c97bfa8a731339045f171c7321edfb9147aa62e59173b87f124
transactionIndex        75
type                    2
blobGasPrice            
blobGasUsed             
authorizationList       
to                      0x94d9ba56C4F7D1c7890d59ce71ac77c098448907
➜  foundry-simple-storage-f24 git:(master) ✗ cast call 0x94d9ba56C4F7D1c7890d59ce71ac77c098448907 "retrieve()" --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL 
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000159
➜  foundry-simple-storage-f24 git:(master) ✗ 

So please mention why I should need an RPC URL to deal with the view functions
My set-up

Ubuntu
Framework - Foundry
command line - zsh

[All the addresses are fake and all the private keys are fake I have used a basic command lines these are not suppose to be used in production level or with real money]

Put very simply, when you are using Anvil, you have the blockchain right there on your computer, running locally. It's still using an RPC call to get the data (I'd assume), since that's just how blockchain data is retrieved. I assume that cast, being a tool in the same suite (Foundry), knows how to 'look' for a running local Anvil chain, saving you the hassle of figuring out how to configure the RPC in order to query. When we're talking about something like Sepolia, though, I'd assume cast doesn't assume you're running a Sepolia node locally (even if you are). How would cast know where to find the data? It needs an RPC call to a node in order to query the chain to get the data for you, so it needs the config data.
Does that make sense?

Yes conceptually this is nice and makes sense.
